# change TabActivity title dynamically according to selected activity tab data

Tags: android

i have created MyTabActivity extending  TabActivity class with two tabs.

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setTitle("My App Name");

      final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1).setIndicator(TAB_1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)).setContent(new Intent(this, first.class)));

      tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2).setIndicator(TAB_2, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2)).setContent(new Intent(this, second.class)));

       tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

       public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

          }
       });

       tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(TAB_1);
    }
}
```

i need to change the title of MyTabActivity according to change in one of activity data.

```
public class first extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        //change the MyTabActivity title from here ???
   }

}
```

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get your `TabActivity` inside child `Activity` like this.
If you are in `FirstActivity` or `SecondActivity` try something like this.

```
MyTabActivity myTabs = (MyTabActivity) this.getParent();
myTabs.setTitle("This is First cool Activity");
```

you can do the same in `SecondActivity`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for answer adil,but its not working . Do i need to call any UI refresh kind of function after set title??

Comment: Actually my FirstActivity is extended from ListActivity this is the problem its not happening?